# linq select query supposed to return some value but it is returning 0

Tags: c#, linq

```
public static decimal getall(decimal number) {
    decimal sigma = (from Sigma_Table in db.Sigma_Tables
                     where Sigma_Table.Defect_Rate < number
                     select (decimal)Sigma_Table.Sigma_Value).Min();
    return sigma;
}
```

`Defect_Rate` < `number` condition should be satisfied and than I want minimum value of `Sigma_Value`.

Comment: show the table contents of `Sigma_Tables`?

Comment: It has some value but it is returning 0.00000

Comment: can you just show that table to **prove**  'It has some value'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use extension method syntax for your case:

```
public static decimal GetAll(decimal number)
{
    return db.Sigma_Tables.Where(x => x.Defect_Rate < number)
                          .Select(x => (decimal)x.Sigma_Value)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty() // we need it, if null selected
                          .Min();
}
```